# Custom UIView that sticks to the keyboard in iOS objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, keyboard

I want to make a custom UIView that sticks to the keyboard, I used input Accessory view, but it doesn't stay on my view controller when the keyboard is away. How can I have a UIView that I've constrained to the bottom of my view controller to stick to the keyboard (like the input accessory view) in iOS Objective-C?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an IBOutlet for bottomConstraint of the view. I assume it is a direct subview of ViewController's view and it should be on the bottom when keyboard is hidden.

```
@IBOutlet weak var bottomConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

Subscribe to keyboard notifications in viewWillAppear:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(showKeyboard), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(hideKeyboard), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
```

Unsubscribe in viewDidDisappear:

```
NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
```

Later in your ViewController:

```
@objc func showKeyboard(_ notification: NSNotification) {
    let info = notification.userInfo
    let rectValue = info![UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue
    if let keyboardSize = rectValue?.cgRectValue.size {
        bottomConstraint.constant = keyboardSize.height
        view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}

@objc func hideKeyboard(_ notification: Notification) {
    bottomConstraint.constant = 0
    view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

**Objective-C:**

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
}

-(void)keyboardWillShow: (NSNotification *) notification {
    CGSize keyboardSize = [[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
    _bottomConstraint.constant = keyboardSize.height;
    [view layoutIfNeeded];
}

-(void)keyboardWillHide: (NSNotification *) notification {
    _bottomConstraint.constant = 0;
    [view layoutIfNeeded];
}
```

Comment: Would have preferred Objective-C. If you can edit your answer please.

Comment: @OmotayoOluwatobi You're welcome ;)

Comment: If you don't use autolayout for some reason, you should update the frame manually instead of changing bottomConstraint.constant

Comment: I'm using Auto layout and it worked perfectly. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to add inputAccessoryView to your textfield.

example

```
self.mytextField.inputAccessoryView = view;
```

Hope this fix your problem

Comment: This doesn't fix the problem. Input accessory view disappears when the keyboard is not appearing. I want my cure to appear where I originally placed it even when keyboard isn't showing.

Comment: Ohh I see in this case you need to add view to your bottom. And with keyboardwillshow/keyboardwillHide notification you need to change the position of that view

Comment: you can take help from this http://kingscocoa.com/tutorials/keyboard-content-offset/

Comment: How do I make it stick to the keyboard like the input accessory view then?